# Azure Terraform Function App 'application_stack' block

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

I'm trying to deploy Azure Functions App with Terraform using the latest version of the provider as described in the documentation here: https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/linux_function_app

My Terraform block looks like:

```
resource "azurerm_linux_function_app" "function_app" {
  depends_on                 = [azurerm_storage_account.example, azurerm_service_plan.app_service_plan]
  name                       = "example-linux-function-app-6375367"
  resource_group_name        = var.resource-group-name
  location                   = var.location
  service_plan_id            = azurerm_service_plan.app_service_plan.id
  storage_account_name       = azurerm_storage_account.example.name
  storage_account_access_key = azurerm_storage_account.example.primary_access_key
  app_settings = {
    "WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE" = 1,
    "AzureWebJobsStorage" = azurerm_storage_account.example.primary_connection_string

  }
  site_config {
    application_stack = {
      python_version = "3.10"
    }
  }
}
```

I am trying to specify the version of Python I want to use inside the application_stack block, which as far as I can tell from the Terraform documentaton needs to be inside the site_config block.

I am getting error on TF plan:

```
│ Error: Unsupported argument
│ 
│   on functions.tf line 34, in resource "azurerm_linux_function_app" "function_app":
│   34:     application_stack = {
│ 
│ An argument named "application_stack" is not expected here. Did you mean to
│ define a block of type "application_stack"?
```

I've tried taking that block out of the site_config block.. still fails.

Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong, please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You set an object like this in Terraform:

```
application_stack = {
      python_version = "3.10"
    }
```

You set a block like this:

```
application_stack {
      python_version = "3.10"
    }
```

In this case, You need to set a block.

Comment: Oh my, do you ever just want the ground to open up and swallow you whole? Thanks!

Comment: Hehe such a small thing right? You probably stared at it for hours. Been there! I feel you! I always lol after I discovery my stupidity! Ah to be human! Am I right?

Comment: Hello, I created a linux function app with similar configuration. But still the general settings shows the Stack as `.Net` instead of `Python 3.9`. May I know if there is a bug?

Comment: Looks like the above was an RBAC issue.